# How can I reduce splash from faucets with rectangular outlets?

Tags: bathroom, kitchens, faucet

I just moved into a new flat and I have a problem with the kitchen and bathroom faucets.

They are extremely splashy (if opened suddenly the water will spill out of the sink!) and whenever I clean the dishes, the kitchen easily becomes a watery mess. The bathroom faucet does not even have an aerator!

I'm no hydraulic expert so I took pictures of both the faucets.

Bathroom (nozzle size: approx. 32mm x 5mm):
[image: Bathroom Faucet 1]
[image: Bathroom Faucet 2]

Kitchen (nozzle size: approx. 30mm x 8mm):
[image: Kitchen Faucet 1]
[image: Kitchen Faucet 2]

Now, a few questions:

1. Do you think I could solve the problem by just adding / replacing the aerators? If so, I have took a look on the internet but I have no idea of what kind and size of aerator I should buy since I did not find any "perfect" match. The "unregular" rectangular shape does not help either.
2. How can I replace these aerators? Should I pull them? I haven't found anything to unscrew.

I hope I explained my problem in enough depth.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Unfortunately, these are very unusual devices (they look like a "form rather than function" type of tradeoff), and they won't match anything even close to standard. You likely have to replace the whole units.

Comment: The faucet with the aerator appears to have some type of rust or residue build-up. This may be cleared by submerging it in a bowl of CLR. CLR is a calcium -lime-rust remover. I would try to stack  upside down pots in the sink stacked high enough to let the bowl cover the faucet end. The issue in the bathroom may be that the aerator got clogged and was removed by a previous tenant.

Comment: find the shutoff valves under the sink and partially close them

Comment: Ok perfect. Thank you very much for all your suggestions! Daniel is right, it seems that "form rather than function" is what the landlord thought when installed these faucets. Thank you all again for your suggestions!

Comment: I suggest you follow mikes suggestion but I would use small plastic bags and hold in place with a zip tie or twist tie. It will take some time but do not over do it. Try vaseline on the chrome finish or something better if you have it to protect it.

Comment: 1: no. 2: because you can't. 3: these suck, please stop making me put them in. Nothing my hand ever comes into contact with should be a square. This includes cabinet handles.

Answer (score 1):

The bathroom sink looks like it has a waterfall faucet.  It's possible someone removed the flow restrictor from the cartridge because they wanted more "splashy".

This is not a simple repair.  You should contact the landlord to fix the abnormal faucets.

Answer (score 0):

Those elegant faucets do not have aerators!   You need to find laminar flow aerators to alleviate the issue.  Unfortunately you probably need to buy new faucets!